# Matrix cannot be saved in MATLAB

Tags: string, matlab, matrix, save

I want to save two strings into one matrix but I receive the following error:

> Error using save Cannot create 'LayersProperties.mat' because 'Layers
>   Properties' does not exist.
>
> Error in Layers (line 29) save('Layers
>   Properties\LayersProperties.mat', 'LayersList', 'TabList')

Here is my code:

```
 clear all
clc

% CREATE THE LIST OF DIFFERENT LAYERS
LayersList = {
    'Name'                  'k [W/m/K]'     'D [mm]'        'e [-]'        'Color R'   'Color G'  'Color B'

    'Glass 3.0'             1.00            3.000           0.92           0.6          0.8         1
    'EVA DuPont Elvax'      0.23            0.2500           0.00           0.8          1           1
    'Solar Cell'            180.00          0.180           0.00           0            0.45        0.74
    'Bcksht DuPont 0.10'    0.36            0.100           0.90           1            1           1

    'Bcksht DuPont 0.20'    0.36            0.200           0.90           1            1           1
    'Bcksht DuPont 0.30'    0.36            0.300           0.90           1            1           1
    'Bcksht DuPont 0.40'    0.36            0.400           0.90           1            1           1
    'Bcksht DuPont 0.50'    0.36            0.500           0.90           1            1           1
    'Bcksht DuPont 0.60'    0.36            0.600           0.90           1            1           1

    'PVB Saflex PA41'       0.19            0.760           0.00           0.8          1           1
    'Si rub. ELASTOSIL'     1.30            0.450           0.00           0.8          1           1
    'POE-based ENGAGE'      0.29            0.450           0.00           0.8          1           1

    };

TabList = {
    'Name'         'rho_tab [Ohm m]'  'T_R_coeff [1/�C]'  'k [W/m/K]' 
    'Copper'       1.53E-08            3.90E-03            50                   
    };
save('Layers Properties\LayersProperties.mat', 'LayersList', 'TabList')
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

When encountering such a problem try checking if Matlab sees that the folder actually exists:

```
isfolder('Layers Properties')
```

I'm guessing it will return false. Then, for safety, prefer to use absolute paths and have you script ensure Matlab is running in the proper location:

```
disp(cd()) % shows your current directory

cd(fileparts(mfilename(fullpath))) % goes to the folder where the running script is located

fullfile(cd(), 'Layers Properties') % builds the absolute path to the Layers Properties folder.
```

Probably this would solve your problem:

```
save(fullfile(cd(), 'Layers Properties', 'LayersProperties.mat'), 'LayersList', 'TabList')
```

**EDIT**: If, as the new image shows, you already are on the Layers Properties folder, then you can simply do:

```
save('LayersProperties.mat', 'LayersList', 'TabList')
```

Comment: I tried it but did not work. Actually since I am in the working folder, it should not be the problem.

Comment: Try replacing the space in the folder's name with an under score `Layers_Properties` (it's usually worth the shot)

Comment: @Hamed if you are working in folder `testfolder`, you can not save as `save('testfolder/something.mat')`, its not how it works. You need to just `save('something.mat')`. If you want a folder within the folder you are working at, then you need `save('./subfolder/something.mat')`. Please read the documentation on how folder path work.